# Can a regular expression replace rule being written for these conditions?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to submit some information to an API but one of the error messages I get back is:

> Field must contain only: upper case letters (A-Z), numbers (0-9), full
>   stop (.), forward slash (/), dash (-), Ampersand (&) and space

Using regular expression in PHP, can a rule be written that replaces any characters other than the ones specified in the error message?

I suck at regular expression but I bet this is quite easy for someone else! Thank you.

I can obviously set the whole thing to strtoupper() so the first bit I can take care of!

Comment: Take a look at negated character classes.

Comment: I think `[^A-Z0-9./&-]` would do it. with http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Sorry can you provide the full line of code I need please? Am I using preg_match / str_replace? Not sure how it works. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `preg_replace('#[^A-Z0-9\./\-&]#', '', $var)`

Comment: Look at the manual.

Comment: I tried removing the upper case check but now this returns blank: $var = preg_replace('#[^0-9\./\-&]#', '', $var);

Comment: Sorry forget that! This now works: $var = preg_replace('#[^A-Z0-9a-z\./\-&]#', '', $var);

Comment: The `.` and `/` don't need to be escaped in a character class (if the `/` is being used as delimiter it would). @JamesWilson your regex is allowing lowercase characters as well, `a-z` doesn't belong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `preg_replace`.

Example: `$str = preg_replace('/[^A-Z\d.\/\-&]+/', '', $str);`

Explanation:

> - [^A-Z\d./-&]+ match a single character not present in the list    below
>
>   - Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving     back as needed [greedy]
>   - A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
>   - \d match a digit [0-9]
>   - . the literal character .
>   - / matches the character / literally
>   - - matches the character - literally
>   - & a single character in the list & literally (case sensitive)